# Executing mySQL query in PHP with Dynamic Table name

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysqli, dynamic-sql

I have a an android app which sends the table name as a parameter to a php script for executing a mySQL query. 
Problem is the table-name is a parameter (hence dynamic). I tried using the `{$table_name}` and backticks as suggested in some of the questions I read here, but nothing seems to work. 
Can someone tell the solution to this problem?

```
    <?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "mmm";
    $connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $tabn= $_POST['tabn'];
    $dt=$_POST['dt'];
    $query="INSERT into $tabn VALUES('$dt')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result)
    {
    $response["success"]=1;
    }
    else
    {
    $response["error"]=1;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    ?>
```

The php script is as given above. I am getting `error = 1` as the output in the android LogCat window.

Comment: can you echo $query and run it directly in your phpmyadmin ,then u can easily come to kow whats the problem

Comment: Have you tried `==1`, with 2x `=` signs instead of 1?

Comment: If I echo it where will it be displayed? And what command to execute that particular query in phpmyadmin?

@Fred Single = is only assignment. == is used for checking if the condition is true.

Comment: can you paste what have echoed,here

Comment: The Php script echoes a Json response to an android app.

You want me to send the query to the app along with the response?

Comment: NO, you just echo your $query and paste that text of that query here so that i will look into it , is it having any problem or not

Comment: Try to use your `INSERT` with real table name and value.not from the `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1):

Place

```
if(mysql_errno()){
   die(mysql_error());
}
```

Just after

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

It will show you MySQL error.

**OR:**

```
if(mysql_errno()){
    $response["error"]   = 1;
    $response["message"] = mysql_error();
} else {
    $response["success"] = 1;
}
```

Instead of:

```
if($result){
    $response["success"] = 1;
} else {
    $response["error"] = 1;
}
```

Comment: I did not vote down you. But it is a comment. i will vote up you

Comment: Thanks, but it does not matter. Im just curious, if there is something wrong. OP might have better debugging with this snippet.

Comment: Sorry I am not able to vote you up because my reputation is less. But putting your code actually displayed the error using which I could correct the problem. 

Thanks. :)

Comment: Just choose the answer as the solution if it helped. U`re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tablename = $_POST['gettable'];
$data='this is data you want to insert';
mysql_query("insert into `$tablename`(`data`) values('$data')");
```

> 

```
$tablename
```

It get the name of the table where data will insert.

```
$data
```

this is your data you want to insert.

When you want to insert data in your database and you want to select
 different table in one query. Then using this query you can insert data
 on different table.